# Core Data and unique UIImage per object

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, uiimage, save

I am making a simple app where the user can create severals objects which are saved with CoreData.

My problem is, I want each object to have an image linked to it. The image is brought by the iphone camera or the user personal Camera roll, so the images will have a pretty high weight (> 1MB each I think).
I read that when the weight of images is that high, the good way to handle this is to save the  images in the documentsDirectory folder, and save the path to coreData. I achieved this pretty easily.

But how do I find a path name for the image to be linked to an unique object? CoreData does not really handle unique IDs, and two objects can have the same name... I searched around objectID but it's not working really good and I'm not sure it's the good way to handle this.

Do you have any idea? Is there an other simple way I am totally missing? Thank you in advance.

Comment: what you mean by unique group?

Comment: Unique object. Sorry typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use coredata's objectID as identifier

```
id uri = [self sanitizeFilename:coreDataObject.objectID.URIRepresentation];
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", uri];
```

helper sanitizeFilename:

```
- (NSString *)sanitizeFileNameString:(NSString *)fileName {
    NSCharacterSet* illegalFileNameCharacters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/\\?%*|\"<>"];
    return [[fileName componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:illegalFileNameCharacters] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
}
```

Comment: Is that ok to use and alterate objectID like this? I did not dare to do something like that.

Comment: well I do it all the time, of course that ID is not stable across multiple devices, but for purposes like this, it works

Answer (score 1):

Just create an object_id number property in your CoreData model entity description and each time a new object is created increment this property by one and assign it to the object, then use a naming convention like

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"object_%d_img.png", idNumber];`

And save it to `NSDoctumentsDirectory`.

Then in object's `- (void)prepareForDeletion` method delete the image.

As for how to increment the id value, create a method that will fetch an object with biggest id value - simply get all objects with sort descriptor by id desc and use it + 1 when creating a new entity.

Comment: Manual uniqueID. Good answer, but I was looking for something more "official". Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Daij-Djan. I created version for Swift:

```
        var itemObjectId:String = item.objectID.URIRepresentation().absoluteString!
    var fileName = NSString(format:"%@.png", FileHelper.sanitizeFileNameString(itemObjectId)) as String
```

Helper for sanitize:

```
struct FileHelper {
 static func sanitizeFileNameString(fileName:String) ->String {
    let illegalFileNameCharacters:NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "/\\?%*|\"<>")
    let components : [String] = fileName.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(illegalFileNameCharacters)
    let joinedString = join("", components)
    return joinedString
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

I think you'll need to generate the unique id by your self. Since a user can have several objects. so maybe the image id could be named as such

```
userId-objectId-somesalt
```

save the value to the object's path

Comment: not concrete enough IMO -- its the same eugene said basically

Comment: @Daij-Djan take a look at answered time. there was no answers when I tried to answer it